# Tool to manage and/or make available a list of my publications on the web? 

Tags: citations, website, productivity, tools, reference-managers

This some kind of follow up question to [How to prevent plagiarism of my papers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/712/102), since I've been clearly convinced that it was in my best interest to put my own papers on my webpage.

Now, since I need to make the effort to put them, I might as well try to do it in a nice way. Right now, I'm using [bibtex2html](http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/bibtex2html/), which is a tool I can run locally, taking a bibtex file with my publications (that I create manually), and that outputs the resulting HTML, that I can copy/paste to my webpage.

I like it, but it can sometimes be complicated to use, so I was wondering if there exist some other tools? My ideal tool would be some tool where I could put the bibtex (one for each publication) and the pdf, and that would create a kind of database, such that I could sort my publications easily.

(Note: Right now, my webpage is hosted directly on Wordpress, so I can't host directly a PhP script, but if there were a really good tool, I could try to host my webpage myself.)

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Do you want a) an online tool to manage bibliography b) a tool to make a list of your publications?

Comment: I want a tool to make and manage my list of publications, thanks for pointing this out, I reformulate. Is it better now?

Comment: Better. `Manage` is a tricky word than can mean almost anything + `my personal list of publications` is a much broader term (may be yours, maybe just collected by you) that `list of my publications`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could consider hosting it via one of the reference / citation managers, such as [CiteULike](http://CiteULike.org/) or [Mendeley](http://www.Mendeley.com/), which can take imports of Bibtex files. Your own university may (should!) have such a [web-front plus publication database available, for you to embed into your university home page](https://iris.ucl.ac.uk/research/publication/index?upi=APSMI28).

### Wordpress

If your webpage is hosted directly on wordpress.com, then no, you can't host your own PHP script. If it's Wordpress hosted elsewhere, then you should be able to add your own PHP script, by incorporating into your plugin. There are skeleton plugins available to get you started. It may be that asking on [Wordpress.SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) will give you some useful pointers.

### Mendeley

On Mendeley: there is an [embedding plugin for Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mendeleyplugin/). I haven't used it, but it might be worth looking into. Or, on your Mendeley profile web page, select edit, then embed. Or Share > Embed elsewhere on Mendeley pages (groups or whatever).

There's an [article on Beta Science on embedding Mendeley](http://betascience.blogspot.com/2010/05/use-mendeley-to-list-your-publications.html) that may be useful. It uses the same Share > Embed as above, but recommends creating a "Publications" group in the desktop client first, putting your own papers into that, (in order, from oldest to newest). 
Then right-click -> Edit Settings, then under "Collection Access" choose "Public - visible to everyone". Then click "Apply and Sync". Then, from the collection web page, select "embed" to get the appropriate html.

### CiteULike

If you prefer CiteULike, they have an excellent [API](http://wiki.citeulike.org/index.php/Importing_and_Exporting#How_can_I_access_my_library_from_application_X.3F), allowing you to [customise](http://www.citeulike.org/groupforum/2394) your own tools. And the staff on the [discussion forum](http://www.citeulike.org/groupfunc/3124/home) are very responsive (a marked contrast with Mendeley).

### Academia.edu

If you prefer [Academia.edu](http://Academia.edu), you could always embed your [publications page](http://ucl.academia.edu/AndrewSmith/Papers) (and maybe your talks page too) in an iframe

Comment: I unfortunately don't have a university home page, which is why I host my webpage right now directly on wordpress.com. I can put somewhere my publication on the university server, but only the new ones, not the old ones (that I published before joining my current affiliation). Mendeley sounds good though, do you know if it's possible to "export" a list of publications to HTML?

Comment: Why can't you put your old publications on your new web page?  Aren't they just PDF files?  Don't you have copies?

Comment: @JeffE I don't have a university page, which is why I use wordpress, and I'm not sure that I can host PDFs there (I haven't tried though). My research team indexes publications, but only those that are done in the context of my current position. Anyway, the point was that I need to do something, so I was asking if it could be worth learning something new :) Btw, I like yours, do you generate it manually?

Comment: @CharlesMorisset: Yep, it's all home-grow HTML.  (One of these days Real Soon Now I'll automate it, honest.)

Comment: @JeffE Well, I'm basically in one of these days, I could either copy and paste old stuff, or try to automate the process. If you find a nice way to automate Real Soon Now, please let me know :)

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I don't use any (I have a huge bibtex file for the references I want to put in papers, and spotlight to find the pdf on my hard-drive or directly google), and I have a single bibtex file for my own publications, and then I use bibtex2html. But I'm considering improving this part of my workflow :)

Comment: Have any of you guys used [ENDNOTE](http://www.endnote.com/) to manage your list of publications?! What are your impressions about that?!

Comment: It would be good to add mention of Zotero as well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zotero

Comment: Also Zotero and Bibsonomy.

Answer (score 16):

You can also try out [Google Scholar Citations](http://scholar.google.com/citations), which is a new service for showing the citation count for all your papers. As an example, [here's my small list](http://scholar.google.com/citations?user=NHu36_oAAAAJ).

Answer (score 10):

## Bibbase

I think that [**BibBase**](http://www.bibbase.org/) would be a perfect solution if you can at least run CGI scripts; instructions can be found [on this page](http://www.bibbase.org/help/) (if you can run PHP then it's even simpler).  You need to feed it a Bibtex file, but if you use Mendeley then it can automatically grab it from there.

**Update**: Bibbase now allows you to use just javascript.  (h/t ChristianF)

> BibBase makes it easy for scientists to maintain their publications pages. As a scientist, you simply maintain a BibTeX-file of your publications, including links to the papers, and BibBase does the rest. When a web user visits your publications page, **BibBase dynamically generates an always up-to-date HTML page from the BibTeX file, and even allows the user to sort the publications** by other than the default ordering (e.g. year, author, keywords, research area, publication type).

[Here is an example of the output.](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Efritz)

## A custom alternative

I happen to have a departmental server that doesn't allow PHP or CGI; you can read about what I do to solve this problem [on my blog](http://scienceinthesands.blogspot.com/2011/10/managing-publication-lists-in-html.html) and see the kind of output generated [on my group's site](http://numerics.kaust.edu.sa/publications.html).  An even more jazzed-up version, which is searchable and filterable, is [on my own site](http://www.davidketcheson.info/publications.html).

Comment: Thanks, BibBase does look good! It's a shame I can't run PHP/CGI on Wordpress ... I guess I really need to a decent webpage.

Comment: BibBase now allows embedding via JavaScript. While this is not an ideal solution, since some search engines will not index the resulting list, it is super easy and widely supported.

Answer (score 8):

An even easier solution that doesn't require anything except the ability to upload a BibTeX file is [Exhibit](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Exhibit/For_Authors). It takes your bibtex, does some javascripting on it, and renders the result. It seems CSS-stylable, and even allows for faceted search.

Comment: That looks great, thanks! But do you know if there a way I could extract the generated HTML? I'm using for now directly wordpress.com, as so I can't put the correct HTML webpage there (because I need to insert stuff in the header), but I can run it locally, that gives a nice page, but I can't directly get the generated HTML :(

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, there is a direct way to embed this in a wordpress site: http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Exhibit/How_to_embed_an_Exhibit_in_a_WordPress_blog

Comment: Yes, indeed, but it only works if you're hosting your own Wordpress blog, not when it's hosted directly on wordpress.com :( (but I know you said it doesn't answer my question).

Comment: ah, so it doesn't answer your question in two ways :(. sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

I'm super lazy and I just use Mendeley's group widget.

- Make a group for your publications
- Dump all of your publications into the group. Hopefully all of the metadata is determined for you.
- Use the widget to generate the code for you.

Result looks like:

```
<iframe src="http://www.mendeley.com/groups/1281613/_/widget/27/3/" 
frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="width:260px;
height:550px;"></iframe>
<p style="width:260px"><a href="http://www.mendeley.com/groups/1281613/swartz-lab/"
title="Swartz Lab on Mendeley">Swartz Lab</a></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Unfortunately, the embedding of the result does not look very good (a single very long line), could you please try to fix it? :)

Comment: See also http://blog.mendeley.com/tag/my-publications/ or http://bibbase.org/

Answer (score 4):

If your paper are on [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/) you can use [myarticles widget](http://arxiv.org/help/myarticles).

It requires obtaining an [arXiv author identifier](http://arxiv.org/help/author_identifiers), which allows you to display your preprints by typing `http://arxiv.org/a/[user]`.

An example of the widget below:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness, I would also mention [ResearcherID](http://www.researcherid.com), a service similar to (but older than) Google Scholar citations, courtesy of Thompson Reuters. They've got badges and similar fancy links that you can put on your homepage.

I just use it as a convenient list and tool for anybody obsessed with h-indices and impact factors.

Answer (score 4):

Just a little follow-up on my own question. I've recently moved my webpage to a server I manage, which allows me to use PHP scripts, and I came across the excellent [Bibtex Browser](http://www.monperrus.net/martin/bibtexbrowser/).

Basically, I just have my own bibtex file on my server, and the publications list is automatically generated from a very simple PHP script. It seems to work as well as [Exhibit](http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Exhibit/For_Authors), that Suresh mentioned, and although it does not answer exactly my original question (since it requires the ability to run scripts), I thought I would put it here for completeness :)

Comment: There's a hosting service for Bibtex Browser called my.publications.li [example](http://my.publications.li/st/rlucas) -- you can integrate the output in other sites, including a Content Management System (CMS) if you can use javascript. If you are good with CSS, you can tweak the format of the output.

Answer (score 1):

I know the topic is old, but I have recently developed a solution that fits the question very well - just in case other people are looking for the same information.

You can try [BibSpace](https://github.com/vikin91/BibSpace). It was created to manage publications of a group and display them automatically on the webpage. It has many fancy features and new features are being developed actively. There is a demo available. The software is free and open source. (Disclaimer: I am the author of this tool).

Answer (score 0):

If you are a user of [Wordpress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) and [Zotero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zotero), then you can use the [Zotpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/zotpress/) plugin to display Zotero citations inside your Wordpress blog.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Academic theme](https://themes.gohugo.io/academic/) based on [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) is a nice theme specifically catered towards academic researchers. For publications, it has an option to directly [import from a list in the BibTex format](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/managing-content/#create-a-publication), which could be exported from a reference manager such as [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/).

Subsequently, you also have the option to control the format the list is displayed in, add external links (such as to the published paper or code), and create a list of selected publications. The theme also provides visitors to your page the option to filter publications by title, authors, year, and publication type, without needing any manual setup.

Beyond this, the theme can also be used to build an entire personal or laboratory website, with individual pages for lab members. It also provides instructions for hosting with [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) (free) or [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/).

Screenshot from the [demo page](https://academic-demo.netlify.app/publication/) for reference:

[image]

References:

1. [Theme homepage](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/)
2. [Demo website](https://academic-demo.netlify.app/), and [more examples of individual and group websites in use](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/#expo)
3. [Documentation](https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/)

<sub>Note: I am not an author and am not affiliated with the creators of this theme.</sub>