# Presenting the publications of a research group online

Tags: website, online-publication

I'm looking for advice on presenting the research publications of my group on our webpage. Most groups seem to go with a simple publication list, sorted by year and maybe publication type. But there are also more elaborate implementations up to browseable publication directories (e.g., http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~sontag/papers.html ). What would be your recommendation for creating an online presence for research publications that is

- informative and useful for readers,
- visually pleasant, and
- easy to maintain for us?

I'd also be interested in links to websites that you see as role models for this issue.

Comment: If you use Drupal, see http://squobble.blogspot.com/2013/09/new-drupal-web-site-for-our-research.html

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/719/tool-to-manage-and-or-make-available-a-list-of-my-publications-on-the-web

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [BibBase.org](http://bibbase.org). It's a free web service that I created with the aim to solve the problem you describe. I was originally motivated by the third point (easy to maintain). As input you can use a bibtex file, Zotero, or Mendeley, and unlike bib2html you don't need to rerun any program after making changes to your input. Visitors can resort by different criteria (author, year, keyword, number of downloads, type), get the bibtex source entry (even when not using bibtex as input), and subscribe to an RSS. Here is an example: http://www.isi.edu/integration/karma/#publication

*(Disclaimer: I'm the creator of BibBase.)*

Answer (score 1):

My dreamed interface puts on the left a list of topics, a list of authors and possibly some other list (venue, maybe). Clicking on them filters the papers that appear on the right.

The papers on the right are in a table that can be sorted by year or title (or possibly something else, number of cites to that paper maybe). On each row there are two icons, one is a PDF icon that leads to the PDF file, the other one is a TeX icon that leads to a GIT repository with the TeX source.

All this can be done (for instance) in Javascript with the data coming from a JSON file that would be the only thing you would need to update to maintain this, so it's quite maintainable. This is my dream. Reality is very far from it, but it may serve as inspiration to you.