# Display of Publications for Personal Website

Tags: citations, website

I've seen a number of sites and web controls for presenting a list of papers (e.g., in BibTex format) on one's personal website.  Some sites also allow you to manage your citation list, then link to a list of publications.  I was wondering about people's experiences with these different tools and the pros/cons.  While I've historically just manually dumped my refs in HTML format for my site, I'm looking to use something a bit more elegant and maintable these days.

Ideally, I would like it to have the following characteristics:

1. Easy to add/edit papers (e.g., generate from BibTex, Mendeley, online storage, etc.)
2. Splitting papers into groups (e.g., journal papers, conference papers, etc.)
3. Decent fallback display for users with JS disabled.  Ideally, no change at all.
4. Papers sortable by year
5. Can specify links or upload pre-print PDF's that users can download

Does anyone know how well existing solutions stack up on these?

Comment: My colleague wrote some PHP scripts that [do exactly that](http://www.sat.ltu.se/publications).  The source is just a bibtex file with a few extra fields.

Comment: You can also use [Exhibit](http://www.simile-widgets.org/exhibit/), as in [David Karger's publication list](http://people.csail.mit.edu/karger/papers.html).

Comment: I think this question has already been asked and answered [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/719/tool-to-manage-and-or-make-available-a-list-of-my-publications-on-the-web/788#788).  If you disagree, you should explain (in the question) how your question is different.

Comment: Ahha. I did a number of searches to try to find this question (as I was pretty sure it must have been asked already), but did not find that one.  If possible, it would be useful to amend the tags on the other one.  "Scientific Productivity" seems unrelated and "Citations" (which are what is in a bibliography) is missing.

Comment: I would say, however, that the existing question leaves a lot to be desired for people noting characteristics of different options (e.g., linking pre-prints, noscript issues).  I could, I suppose, ask those each separately, but that is not a very satisfactory option.  What does one do when your question is a duplicate, but has a much lower level of specification?