# Is there any self hosted alternative to Researgate/Academia/GScholar

Tags: website

This morning I've been looking for a self-hosted alternative to Researgate/Academia/Google Scholar/linkedIn; I'm currently using WP Resume but what I want is something where taxonomy etc are already adapted for a scientific profile.

To be more specific, a tool or set of tools

- where you can add references such as papers/proceedings/Etc, add items to them and organize them
- which can parse google scholar and others to get citations stat (a cron job could trigger that)
- where you have your profile page with skills, lab(s) etc
- of course with a sexy interface (usually the biggest challenge in opensource projects)

Somehow a ideal mix between zotero.org for displaying references and researchgate/academia for their interface and profile pages. And aggregating stats from various sources. http://simile-widgets.org/exhibit3/ is nice and could be used like Zotero does for timelines

I've checked github and the vast web but I found nothing. The homemade technical solution seems to be wp-publications+wp-resume+exhibit3+lots of taxonomy and design work

Have you heard about something close to what I want?

Thank you reader(s)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tool to manage and/or make available a list of my publications on the web?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/719/tool-to-manage-and-or-make-available-a-list-of-my-publications-on-the-web)

Comment: Those three sites all do somewhat different things.  What are the specific features you're looking for? (please edit the question to include them)

Comment: Having your very own page tucked away in the dark recesses of the Internet serves no discernible purpose. Noone will ever see it.

Comment: @vonbrand on the other hand, it's frustrating when the only contact information available for a researcher is their Google Scholar/Researchgate/Academia etc profile. If that's your only online presence, and it doesn't include an email address, you will be unreachable.

Comment: @Tyler, then add a contact address...

Comment: @vonbrand "in the dark recesses of the Internet serves" Hmmm nope
it appears to be in second position well supported by LinkedIn etc which gives me the good ranking. And WordPress gives me a well tagged html. And since my content is original, all SEO markers are for my benefit
but my question is not about the relevance of the idea